# How to import csv data into sql using powershell import-csv

Tags: c#, powershell, csv

I have used similar code from one of the questions and used that to import the csv data to sql table but having a weird error. unable to locate it in my editor and needed an additional pair of eyes.

```
$database = 'ABC_Test'
$server = 'ABCTEST.com'
$table = 'XYZ\A12.ABC_PayCode'
Import-CSV C:\Users\Downloads\sampledata.csv | ForEach-Object {Invoke-Sqlcmd `
-Database $database -ServerInstance $server `
-Query "insert into $table VALUES ('$($_.EMPLOYEE_ID)','$($_.FIRST_NAME)','$($_.LAST_NAME)','$($_.WORK_DATE)','$($_.EARNINGS_CODE)','$($_.HOURS)')"
}
```

Throws me an error into
Invoke-Sqlcmd : Incorrect syntax near ''.
At \mgroupnet.com\RedirectedFolders\Documents\powershell.ps1:5 char:69

- ... Users\qd90\Downloads\sampledata.csv | ForEach-Object {Invoke-Sqlcmd `
- ```
                                                        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  ```

  - CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Invoke-Sqlcmd], SqlPowerShellSqlExecutionException
  - FullyQualifiedErrorId : SqlError,Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.PowerShell.GetScriptCommand

Comment: Table name needs to be `$table = '[XYX\A12].[ABC_PayCode]'`

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is that the schema and table names have delimited identifiers (`\` and `_`). Your SQL statement must escape them with quotes or brackets:

```
# Brackets
$table = '[XYZ\A12].[ABC_PayCode]'
# Quotes
$table = '"XYZ\A12"."ABC_PayCode"'
```

Note that the schema and table names are escaped separately.

Comment: Its working but unable to get the child item properly. Its only feeding to one column that is.
wfs_workdate
1900-01-01 00:00:00.000. Is this due to bad data or am I missing any conversions?